# Operators AND and OR in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, operators

I have the following query and I receive output with movies of genres different from `Action`.

```
SELECT original_title, genres 
FROM movies
WHERE cast LIKE('%Daniel Craig%') 
   OR cast LIKE('%Christoph Waltz%') 
  AND genres LIKE('%Action%');
```

I want to see only genres that include Action.
This is what I see now:

```
Spectre                          Action|Adventure|Crime
Inglourious Basterds             Drama|Action|Thriller|War
Lara Croft: Tomb Raider          Adventure|Fantasy|Action|Thriller
Quantum of Solace                Adventure|Action|Thriller|Crime
Defiance                         Action|Drama|History|War
Flashbacks of a Fool             Drama
The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo  Thriller|Crime|Mystery|Drama
Cowboys & Aliens                 Action|Science Fiction|Thriller|Western
The Green Hornet                 Action|Crime|Comedy
Dream House                      Drama|Thriller|Mystery
One Life                         Family|Documentary
Skyfall                          Action|Adventure|Thriller
```

Kind regards,
Anna

Comment: what's the content of the `cast` column ? There's no problem with the query in terms of filtering out including `Action`. Are you sure about the query ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan The cast column is `Daniel Craig|Christoph Waltz|Lafaca Seydoux|Ralph Fiennes|Monica Bellucci`

Answer (score 1):

It is `OR` that causes problems. Should probably have been

```
SELECT original_title, 
       genres 
FROM movies
WHERE (   cast LIKE('%Daniel Craig%') 
       OR cast LIKE('%Christoph Waltz%')
      ) 
  AND genres LIKE('%Action%');
```

Comment: I believe it is, @Barbaros. Add yet another film to your collection: `SELECT 'Daniel Craig','Tomb Raider', 'Adventure'   FROM dual` and see what your query returns.

Comment: Good catch. Indeed, I also thought directly like you originally, but you're able to get the point.